# What is best way to redirect on login page in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

If user is not logged in then user should have to be redirect on login page, for that i found function which is working fine for me, i used below function

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{        
    if (\Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest &&
        \Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== Url::to(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl)
    ) {
        \Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl);
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

This is working fine for me, but for this i need to add function in every controller, what i want to do, i need common function where can i perform this action, So can anyone please tell me what is best way to do this ?

Comment: Why don't you use `yii\web\User::loginRequired()`? The function does exactly what you needs and also remembers current url. See Anton M's answer.

Answer (score 18):

You need to add below code in `config/web.php` after `components` part.

```
'as beforeRequest' => [  //if guest user access site so, redirect to login page.
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
            'allow' => true,
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: It works fine for me when I added it under backend or frontend.

Answer (score 3):

Actually if user does not have rights Yii redirects him to login page by it self. 
You can change loginUrl if you have another one. Or you can implement own redirect if for example you use ajax. 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Here is explanation of Yii security 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html