# Trying to get property of non-object on Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, propertyinfo

I want to show data based on user's group id, which is i use

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id
```

in my ModelSearch like this :

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
        ......
        'group_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id,
        'created_date' => $this->dreated_date,
    ]);
```

It works when i have session in the application, but when i don't have session the page show error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

For  `'group_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->group_id,`

How to make the page redirect to login page when i open that page if I don't have any session. Thank You.

EDIT

I added

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl);
}
```

in every action in my contoller that access ModelSearch .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is best way to redirect on login page in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296156/what-is-best-way-to-redirect-on-login-page-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add access control filter for this action.

Add in the controller:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['ID of your action here'],
            'rules' => [
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Or you can add the redirect directly in the action - for example place it at the beginning:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl);
}
```

Comment: I alredy try both of them. But it doesn't work and still get get error Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: So you did something wrong because if you properly identified this error it means that ModelSearch is accessed by guest user.

Comment: It's Already work, i have to add redirect directly in every action in controller. Thanks.

Comment: i have AccessControl and "if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl);
}" in beforeAction, the code go inside the if but don't redirect, and i get the same error...